# Ansible not realiable with apt updates on Ubuntu

Tags: ansible

I created few Ubuntu 14.04 machines vith Vagrant. I have some ansible 2.1 playbook that uses `apt` in some tasks, like:

- update apt
- add docker repo
- add java8 repo

All these tasks fails randomly, on random host. For example, here is simple java8 installation role:

```
- name: Add Oracle Java Repository
  apt_repository:
    repo: 'ppa:webupd8team/java'
    update_cache: yes
    state: present
#  register: result
#  until: result|success
#  retries: 10
  tags: [java]

- name: Accept Java 8 License
  debconf: name='oracle-java8-installer' question='shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1' value='true' vtype='select'
  tags: [java]

- name: Install Oracle Java 8
  apt: name={{item}} state=latest
  with_items:
    - oracle-java8-installer
    - ca-certificates
    - oracle-java8-set-default
  tags: [java]
```

Pretty simple, yet `apt_repository` fails randomly a lot. I had to use retries hack in order to make it work. Issue is reported [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/2951), but this is just one.

The error looks like:

```
fatal: [xx.xx.xxx.x]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "",
"module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n
File \"/home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1454536847.17-86172912102079/apt\", line 2630, in \r\n
 main()\r\n
File \"/home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1454536847.17-86172912102079/apt\", line 603, in main\r\n
 cache = apt.Cache()\r\n
File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py\", line 107, in init\r\n
 self.open(progress)\r\n
File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py\", line 151, in open\r\n
 self._cache = apt_pkg.Cache(progress)\r\n
SystemError: E:Encountered a section with no Package: header,\
 E:Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/us-west-\
 2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_universe_i18n_Translation-en\
, E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.\r\n
", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "parsed": false}
```

Am I missing something? What do you do for production?

Comment: Failing how? What error are you getting? Is there a pattern to the failures?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR please see the linked issue. i will put the error here too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't an Ansible problem, though Ansible certainly isn't helping matters.

This is a problem with `apt` occasionally saving a garbage file (binary of some sort) as a package list, which should be text. [There's been a bug open forever about it](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/886273), and [here's a fix from AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/how-do-i-fix-a-problem-with-mergelist-or-status-file-could-not-be-parsed-err).

In this case, look at the file, confirm it is binary, then delete it:

```
head /var/lib/apt/lists/us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_universe_i18n_Translation-en
rm /var/lib/apt/lists/us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_universe_i18n_Translation-en
```

`apt` will recreate it when `apt-get update` is run.

How do you fix this with Ansible? [There are some workarounds in the ansible issue you found](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/2951), ultimately the apt module should be patched to simply work around this- detect the failure, remove the file, and rerun update. But sending a pull request to Ansible means it won't be released for about a year. I've found it happens rarely enough that I just manually fix it.

Comment: Thnax. For me this happens almost everytime when update apt:(